# How to show the media Controller till the song ends?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am facing the issue in showing the media player .
       1) Showing the media controller for only 3 seconds after that media controller is hidden.
       2) Media controller should destroy only when the activity is closed or back button pressed.
       3) Media controller is viewing the bottom of the activity i want to change the place for media controller  viewing.

```
 public void audioplayer(View view)
{
    mediaController = new MediaController(this);


    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    mediaPlayer.reset();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

    mediaPlayer.start();

    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer((MediaController.MediaPlayerControl) this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.main_audio_view));

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mediaController.setEnabled(true);
            mediaController.show();
        }
    });
}




@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mediaController.hide();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //the MediaController will hide after 3 seconds - tap the screen to make it appear again
    mediaController.show();
    return false;
}

//--MediaPlayerControl methods----------------------------------------------------
public void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void pause() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

public int getDuration() {
    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public void seekTo(int i) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The above code for media controller .In that the media controller is shown for only three seconds.please help me how to solve this.The media player should shown till the song ends and also media controller should hide only when the activity destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

change return statement in `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` to true. and Remove `if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
   {
     mediaPlayer.stop();
   }`
i am also new to android hope it Helps..